# Get value from 2nd slash

Tags: java, string, substring

Below is my string

```
/downloadAPK/D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk
```

I want to get the value **after 2nd slash(/)** which is

```
D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk
```

How should I do this?

**Note :** 
I am getting this string in my rest call in variable `restOfTheUrl`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/downloadAPK/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void downloadFile(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

        String restOfTheUrl = (String) request.getAttribute(
                HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
}
```

I want to get the complete file location

Comment: Hover your mouse over downvote arrow and you will see potential reasons to use it. In this case I am guessing it is lack of shown research or even attempt to solve it yourself.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @PavneetSingh there are 2 problems: "2nd" and "slash", i.e. not "last" and "backslash" ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: To be honest, my downvote are simply because you **asked** for a regex. You know that exist (you use the tag) but didn't bother to try to write one. So I don't see any effort from you here. EDIT : No need to remove the tag, there is a log of every edit ;)

Comment: @PavneetSingh Even OPs example shows that this isn't the case.

Comment: @Tom so in that case i will post the solution if OP shows his efforts :P

Comment: @PavneetSingh Your posted comment ***isn't*** the solution. It won't work. So there is no need to use this as an answer.

Comment: @abhi314 you do understand that the effort we expect from you is to **try** before asking. No sending more code that is out of context.

Comment: @Tom please read my comments carefully , i never said it is a right solution , previous comment was about future answer , there is a `will`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even a better and simple solution `\\/.*?\\/(.*)`

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/99wdIh/1)

`\\/.*?\\/(.*)` : `\\/.*?\\/` match the first two `/` and content between

`(.*)` : capture whatever is after first two `/`

```
    String s = "/downloadAPK/D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk";
    String result=s.replaceAll("\\/.*?\\/(.*)", "$1");
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output :

```
D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk
```

---

You can use a regex with `replceAll`  if there is always one `:` in the input

```
    String s = "/downloadAPK/D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk";
    String result=s.replaceAll(".*([A-Za-z]:.*)", "$1");
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output :

```
D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk
```

`.*([A-Za-z]:.*)` : `.*` matches any character

`([A-Za-z]:.*)` : `[A-Za-z]` match a character like `D`

`()` :  is a capturing group which is represented as `$1`

`:.*`  : will capture all after `:`

Otherwise

```
    String s = "/downloadAPK/D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk";

    // find first index of /
    int index =s.indexOf("/");

    // find second index of /        
    index=s.indexOf("/", index+1);

    // fetch substring from second index+1 of /
    System.out.println(s.substring(index+1));
```

Output :

```
D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure, always colon(:) will exist in string, then you can use this.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String str = new String("/downloadAPK/D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk");
      String subStr1 = new String(":");
      System.out.println("value  "+ str.substring(str.indexOf( subStr1 )-1));
   }
}
```

output:
value  D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk

This code for without colon (:)

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String str = new String("/downloadAPK/D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk");
     System.out.println("before value" + str);
         str = getPattern(str, 2);
      System.out.println("\nAfter value  "+ str);


   }
   public static String getPattern(String str, Integer pos) {
       for(int i = 0; i< pos; i ++) {
       str = str.substring(str.indexOf("/") +1);
              }
       return str;
   }
}
```

**Output**

before value/downloadAPK/D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk

After value  D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk

Comment: Please. explain your solution. Note : you should watch you variable name, don't start with an uppercase

Comment: @shas Thank you for you answer, unfortunately " : " will not always be in the link, currently I am testing in my local machine which is windows but the test server is on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can iteratively find the index. You could also write a recursive version, but this does not perform the substring until the final step; which means it will not pollute the String pool.

```
public class StringUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "/downloadAPK/D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk";
        System.out.println(substring2(path, "/", 2)); // D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk

        String test = "this---is---a---test";
        System.out.println(substring2(test, "---", 3)); // test
    }

    public static String substring2(String src, String str, int offset) {
        if (offset <= 0) {
            return src;
        }
        int index = -1, pos = 0;
        while (pos++ < offset) {
            index = src.indexOf(str, index + 1);
        }
        return src.substring(index + str.length(), src.length());
    }
}
```

Here is a `StringTokenizer` version which handles indexing for you.

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class StringUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "/downloadAPK/D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk";
        System.out.println(substring2(path, "/", 1)); // D:/coinFiles/Coin-v1.1.8.apk

        String test = "this---is---a---test";
        System.out.println(substring2(test, "---", 3)); // test
    }

    public static String substring2(String src, String delim, int offset) {
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(src, delim);
        while (offset-- > 0 && tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            tokenizer.nextToken();
        }
        return join(tokenizer, delim);
    }

    public static <T> String join(Enumeration<T> enumeration, String delim) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            buff.append(enumeration.nextElement());
            if (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                buff.append(delim);
            }
        }
        return buff.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this loop can overflow. For instance if at some point `src.indexOf(str, index + 1);` will return -1 we will start searching for `str` from beginning again.

Comment: @Pshemo I added a `StringTokenizer` response to handle safe index/bound checking.

Comment: This is becoming complex knowing that this is coming from a request with a value always beginning with the same String ;)